# Quarkus: maven deploy the runner jar

Tags: maven, quarkus, maven-deploy-plugin

I need to deploy the quarkus runner jar from maven, however with a basic `mvn deploy` it only deploys the usual .jar and the .pom.

I tried the following plugin:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-executable</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>quarkus/target/quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But it seems that it cannot work this way (file name should be provided in the command line, which is not what I need).

Is there an easy way to deploy the runner jar? Also for a native image?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `builder-helper-maven-plugin` like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-artifacts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifacts>
          <artifact>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner.jar</file>
            <classifier>runner</classifier>
            <type>jar</type>
          </artifact>
        </artifacts>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```